# Integration over D-dimensional euclidean space

Tags: gaussian-integral

I have to show that in D-dimensional Euclidean space:

\begin{align}
\int d^D q=\frac{2\pi^{D/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{D}{2})}\int d q^{D-1}
\end{align}

By the way shouldn't it be $\int dq q^{D-1}$ if it should make any sense?

I was given the hint to look at the gaussian integral:

\begin{align}
\int d^D q e^{-q^2}
\end{align}

But I don't know if I should write it out in D integrals, that is assume

\begin{align}
q^2=(x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_D^2)
\end{align}

I don't know if this approach is useful. I hope someone can help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Gaussian_integrals

Comment: I used the combination of these:http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/volume_11.pdf http://www.phys.vt.edu/~ersharpe/6455/janhand1.pdf